# Get First Element and Remove First Element of Object AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angular-filters

First Filters

```
'use strict';

app.filter('first', function(){
    return function(object){
    var first = first_element_of_object;
    return first;
    }
});
```

Remove First Filters

```
'use strict'

app.filter('removeFirst', function(){
    return function(object){
    var new_one = after_remove_first_element_of_object;
    return new_one;
    }
});
```

HTML Code

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row | removeFirst">{{value}}</td>
    <td>
       <ul ng-init="id = row | first">
         <li ng-repeat="option in options">
           <a ng-href="{{option.link}}/{{id}}" class="btn btn-default">{{option.name}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Here is Rows:

```
[
 {"educationBoardId":1,"educationBoardName":"Dhaka"},
 {"educationBoardId":3,"educationBoardName":"Manikganj"}
]
```

Question-1: How i get the first element of object ??

Question-2: How i remove the first element of object ??

Comment: As far as I understand, you just need to remove the first element of the array. You dont need angularjs for that. Just use splice: var firstElement = array.splice(0,1). after this line array will have first element removed

Comment: i upate my question, take a look please. i need to use AngularJS. Is there any way to find first element using AngularJS ??

Comment: Angularjs works on js only and all the functions/logic is written in js. You are applying the filter there which applies on each item of ng-repeat which in your case is an element of array(reason it is giving an error), you may need to call a function instead which seperates the first element before passing it to ng-repeat as a variable.

Comment: You can console the object you receive in the filter function to see what is coming and how you can handle that. If you are trying to remove the first property of object, then splice wont work as it works on array only, for object you might need to delete it manually using delete obj.firstProperty;